# Por qué es necesario usar Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy haciendo un programa para trabajar con bases de datos en java y tengo un problema con el jdbc, hay cosas que no entiendo.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public ConexionSql(){
        String cadcon="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mibasededatos";
        String user="root";
        String password="root";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         cn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(cadcon,user,password);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error sql: "+e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

y solo funciona si pongo la linea `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` la cual no se que hace,
si la quito al intentar insertar datos `e.getMessage()` devuelve el error: `null` 
y ¿porque tengo que hacer el cast a DriverManager?.
buscando por Internet no he visto que a nadie le suceda esto.
Tengo importado:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement;
```

Trabajo en Xubuntu por si tiene algo que ver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El proceso es:

- Cargas la clase.

  - Al cargarse la clase, se registra como driver JDBC.
- Invocas `DriverManager.getConnection()`. No hay cast a `DriverManager`, llamas a un método estático. Y el cast a `Connection` sobra, porque `getConnection()` ya devuelve una referencia a `Connection`.

  - En función de la URL que le has pasado, `DriverManager` localiza, entre los drivers de BD que tiene registrados, el que se usa para acceder a la base de datos indicada. Java delega en este driver toda la comunicación con la base de datos.

  Así, tú siempre haces `DriverManager.getConnection()`, pero la instancia de `Connection` recuperada será de una subclase distinta para conectarte a MySQL que para Oracle. De todas formas, como todas las instancias tienen que cumplir con la especificación de `Connection`, a tí realmente te da igual.

En sistemas antiguos, para que `DriverManager` tuviera "registrados" los drivers, era necesario cargar la clase en la máquina virtual. Para eso es el `Class.forName()`, simplemente carga la clase con el nombre indicado.

A partir de JDK 6, los drivers JDBC 4 ya se registran automáticamente y no es necesario el `Class.forName()`, sólo que estén en el classpath de la JVM.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` registra el driver de conexión para la base de datos. Cada base de datos usa uno distinto, en tu caso es mysql. ¿Si no registras el driver como quieres que se conecte?

Los proveedores de Bases de datos hacen sus implementaciones para poder conectarse con java a sus bases de datos. Como cada clase de conexión es distinta java proporciona un interfaz para que los proveedores de base de datos se adapten a ella. Entonces cada clase de conexión de cada base de datos implementa esta interfaz `(java.sql.Connection)`, es por ello que tienes que hacer el cast. Al importar tu `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` este implementa internamente `java.sql.Connection`.

Comment: Gracias pero yo he visto códigos por internet que no utilizan ese cast hay alguna otra forma de implementalo ?

Comment: Claro, pero esos códigos usan pool de conexiones o se conectan con hibernate, jpa, myibatis. Y si tienes problemas con esto, `con todo respeto` ¿Como vas a entender un pool de conexiones por ejemplo?

Comment: Soy estudiante estoy empezando.

Comment: `initContext = new InitialContext();`
    

`DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConexionMySQL");`

    `cn = ds.getConnection();`

Comment: No se que es eso?

Comment: Es lo que te digo, quieres correr y todavía no sabes caminar, eso es otra forma de conectarse en java.Pero es mas avanzada. Por eso deberías hacer caso a lo que si entiendes.

Answer (score -1):

```
cn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(cadcon,user,password);

Connection conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
```

Esta es la forma en que se hace la conexión me paso y lo corregí

Comment: import java.sql.*; // importas todo

Comment: Hola elkinprog, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Esta respuesta, aunque puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para darle mejor formato al código, añadir lo que pones en los comentarios directamente en la respuesta, e incluir una descripción de la solución (¿por qué haciendo esto funciona? ¿qué hace exactamente?). Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones. Un saludo.