# No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

He creado un programa de pruebas para conectar a una base de datos Informix 7.31 TD6 con Java y leer los datos de una tabla y me aparece el error de referencia (No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli)

El programa arroja este error solamente cuando en la url de conexión yo escribo "localhost". Si en vez de "localhost" yo escribo el nombre del equipo o la IP no aparece ningún error pero se queda procesando y no hace nada.

He agregado al proyecto todos los .jar de JDBC de Informix, por lo que pienso que algo debe andar mal con el localhost, pero lo tengo así en el archivo hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
::1          localhost
```

por lo que considero que está correcto.
El programa es el siguiente:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class ConexionInformix {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            // Establecer la conexión con la base de datos Informix
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:informix-sqli://compu-01:1526/pruebas:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_gechenique;user=informix;password=informix";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

             // Crear una declaración SQL
             statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Ejecutar una consulta SQL para leer los datos de la tabla
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Tipos_Srv";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

            // Iterar sobre los resultados y mostrar los datos
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("idtipo_srv");
                String nombre = resultSet.getString("descripcion");

                System.out.println("ID: " + id);
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre);
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Cerrar los recursos en orden inverso
            try {
                if (resultSet != null)
                    resultSet.close();
                if (statement != null)
                    statement.close();
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
        }
    }
```

Espero alguno me pueda dar una mano, porque es la primera vez que me sucede.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

me suena a que no estás cargando ni registrando el driver usando `Class.forName("<clase del driver>")`. En la pregunta [Por qué es necesario usar Class.forName](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76160/por-qu%C3%A9-es-necesario-usar-class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver) explican detallado por qué se debe utilizarlo.

En la [documentación de informix](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=database-load-informix-jdbc-driver), indican cómo puedes hacerlo